# What's so special about the <pre> tag in relation to javascript

Tags: html, pre

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.writeln("Hello");
document.writeln("I am new line!");
</script>
```

Output is:

```
Hello I am new line!
```

Code with pre

```
<pre>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.writeln("Hello World!");
document.writeln("Have a nice day!");
</script>
</pre>
```

Output is:

```
Hello
I am a new line!
```

What's so special about the `<pre>` tag? Is it only used for `line breaks`?

Comment: Check this article:  http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlpre.php

Comment: HTML doesn't translate \n to newline. Use a <BR /> or use <pre> or separate paragraphs with <p>.

Answer (score 5):

The `pre` tag works by preserving white-spaces, line feeds etc.

Your javascript is printing `Hello. \n I am a new line`.

Without the `pre` tag, HTML ignores the `\n`. With the pre tag, it honors the `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, a newline in HTML text is meaningless; text lines are stitched together and flow into paragraphs. The `<pre>` tag preserves any newlines inside of it. This has nothing to do with Javascript; it's just the nature of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't really make sense (note the second example prints *"Have a nice day!"*), but I think I get the gist of what you're asking.

Yes, the `<pre>` tag preserves white space. Read the spec:

> The `pre` element represents a block of preformatted text, in which structure is represented by typographic conventions rather than by elements.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-pre-element

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre> tag used to show the values line by line. 
ex: if u put print_r for particular array variable it shows results line by line..
```